# How to add cards in the card view at run time in android app

Tags: android

I have three cards in my activity. But user can add more comments and hence more cards in the view. I am new to android programming. So would like to know how will I add later cards on run time?

Answer (score 1):

You can use recycler view to add views at runtime. Use this tutorial. http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-recyclerview-and-cardview-on-android--cms-23465

Answer (score 0):

Use a `ListView` and add the data to the list and update whenever required using `notifyDataSetChanged()`.